# How to get media of specific instagram account by hashtag?

Tags: facebook, instagram-graph-api

I want to get media of specific Instagram account (my account) by hashtag. I followed the instruction of Instagram Graph API but maybe the result maybe returned all media of all user by hashtag. 
Does anyone have any idea ? Thanks !

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get all of an Instagram business account's posts that include a particular hashtag? One can use the call:

```
<INSTAGRAM_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID>/media?fields=caption
```

To get an Instagram business accounts posts, including the caption. Then, one can parse the caption field to derive what hashtags were used in each post.